# Envolvendos divs com uma class dentro de um laço de repetição

Tags: php, lógica

Tenho o seguinte código php

```
for ($i = 0; $i <6; $i++){
    echo '<div class="item">';
    echo $i;
    echo '</div>';
    }
?>
```

Gostaria que as class até a posição 3 fossem envolvidas por uma div, e as duas classes restantes, fosse envolvidas por outra classe, para que o resultado final seja esse abaixo:

```
<div class="coluna-1">
    <div class="item">0</div>
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
</div>
<div class="coluna-2">
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
</div>
```

Fiz várias tentativas, mas não consegui, a forma que eu estava fazendo tava imprimindo um elemento dentro do outro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dá pra criar uma função e chamar duas vezes:

```
<?php

function colunaDiv($className, $primeiro, $ultimo) {
    echo '<div class="'.$className.'">';

    for($i = $primeiro; $i <= $ultimo; $i++) {
        echo '<div class="item">';
        echo $i;
        echo '</div>';
    }

    echo '</div>';
}

colunaDiv("coluna-1", 0, 4);
colunaDiv("coluna-2", 5, 6);

?>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Daniel, deu super certo, só precisei passar mais dois parâmetros que tinha no código e ficou show